# How can I create a Slack-style emoji picker using React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build an emoji picker using React Native that resembles Slack's emoji picker (see screenshot).  I can handle the searchbox/keyboard part, but I'm not sure how to build the list part. It seems like the `SectionList` would be the best choice, but it doesn't support rendering items using `flexWrap: 'wrap'` and it also doesn't support `numColumns`.  I'm using [emoji-data](https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data) which has over 1,400 emojis.  Is my only choice to build a `SectionList` style component from scratch?  Or does something else exist that would be better for this?

[image: Slack emoji picker]

Comment: I'm investigating same functionality, I think for the category part of emoji panel, we could use `TabBarIOS` or `https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view`. However, it seems like we could not insert an emoji or Image component into TextInput. How did you resolve this issue finally?

Comment: I've added a package for it, although it is same for both android and ios (since I don't like picker for android) - [`react-native-slack-emoji`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-slack-emoji). Although there are some few features remaining to be implemented, but it should solve the other issues.